# Don't know where to start with selecting a row in php

Tags: php, mysql

Ok guys I know this might not be the correct way to ask a question but I have looked as far as I could go. I am a bit stuck on how to go about this problem, probably why I can't find a solution to it. I have a form that the info gets inserted to a db, then you are able to view the info from the database on another page that list everything inserted. My question is how would I go about selecting a row from the table that displays all the info from a row on the db and redirect to another page to edit it? I want to redirect to another page to view/edit all the info.

What I think would work is in the table that shows the info I could put a radio box and have a button at the top to click to edit that row. I don't really know how to assign that radio button to the actual row however.

Here is my table:

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY LastName";
                $result = $mysqli -> query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "
                    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive'>
                        <thead class='thead-dark'>
                            <tr>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>#</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>First Name</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col-1'>M.I.</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Last Name</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Phone</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Address</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Email</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Birth Date</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>EID</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Gender</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Ethnicity</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Status</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>Hours</th>
                                <th class='table-primary' scope='col'>EAP Access</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>";
                    // output data of each row
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class='table-dark'>
                                <td>" . $row['UserID']. "</td>
                              <td>" . $row['FirstName']. "</td>
                              <td>" . $row['Middle']. "</td>
                              <td>" . $row['LastName']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['PrimaryPhone']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['Address'] . $row['City'] . $row['State'] . $row['Zipcode']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['Email']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['DateOfBirth']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['EID']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['Gender']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['Ethnicity']." </td>
                                <td>" . $row['Status']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['Hours']. "</td>
                                <td>" . $row['eapAccess']. "</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
            ?>
```

If I added a `<input type="radio" name="selected">` before the `userID` column like and had a button to select that row, how would I be able to have that row display on a seperate page?

I am still new to php, but this is beyond me and can't find anything remotely close to an answer.

Comment: add an edit button to the table with a link that includes the db table id. create a new page that takes the id from the url, querries the db to dusiplay the data in a form, that can then post back to the db any changes

Comment: @nogad thank you for your help, I’ll look more into that option.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: @tadman I just learned prepared statements so I will transition to that.

Comment: Another thing you'll want to look at is how to use `array` structures to define things so you can generate tables like this programmatically rather than having to copy-paste innumerable lines to get the same effect.

Comment: @tadman I will study up on that thank you

Answer (score 1):

Few steps to be done:

1. add the input radio before before the user ID
2. wrap whole table with the `<form>` elements with defined `method` and `action` attributes
3. add the submit button inside the form to send the values
4. on next script you will receive the value within $_GET or $_POST
5. process all what you need with received user ID

Study more about (search internet for more info):

- HTML forms
- PHP Form Handling
- PHP GET and POST Method Tutorials

Comment: Please don't link to third-rate sites like w3schools. A lot of their advice is wickedly out of date if not dangerously bad especially when it comes to database interfacing code.

Comment: @tadman Ok, man, removed the direct links and suggested to search the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Your  as well as all other information you what to send to another script should be wrapped inside  . 
Set the form action, i.e the script path, and use either POST or GET method( I prefer POST). 
On your next script, you will probably use isset() to check if the userID was received, then you can Carry on from there.